# When hosting a war in jetty, how are META-INF/resources/webjars/ resources picked up?

Tags: servlets, jetty, jetty-9

When we package resources in META-INF/resources/webjars/ folder inside a .jar it shows up http://localhost:port/context/webjars/.

How does this work? Is it part of servlet3 specification? Is there some way to control this behaviour? For the exact same binary sometimes the webjars folder isn't made available by Jetty and we're trying to investigate why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to are Servlet 3.0+ jar bundled web accessible resources.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/web_inf_lib_jar_meta
- https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/

Aka: `WEB-INF/{\*.jar}!/META-INF/resources/`

For a Jetty specific viewpoint...

Starting in Jetty 8+, on deployment, these are unpacked into the WebApp's temp directory and referenced internally for access via the `ServletContext` for that WebApp.